# mysql ini file datadir folder name issue

Tags: mysql, directory, ini

I am struck with an strange issue. I am trying to stop/start mysql after changing the datadir in the mysql.ini.
I have created a folder **F:\testdirformysql\data** and I have given the datadir parameter in the mysql.ini as **F:\Testdirformysql\data**.
Please note the first letter is capital letter in the ini file. But in the folder name it is full small case.
Now I have copied the mysql folder from the installation directory of the MySQL. And started the mysql from service -> start service. Its starting succesfully.

But when I give the datadir parameter in the mysql.ini as **F:\testdirformysql\data** its not starting. Now the first letter of the folder in the ini file is small letter.

My environments are - Windows 7 and Windows XP
Database version Mysql MySQL Server 5.0.

Please forgive me if this is a silly question.

Otherwise Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Either use forward slash F:/path/to/file or double the backslash F:\path\to\file